# Read data from prop property in kernel/driver side

Tags: c, linux, kernel, driver, getproperty

I'm working for a AOSP company, now I want to read data from prop "adb shell getprop" in kernel/driver side.
example:

```
[ro.csc.country_code]: [USA]
```